# Why is the Javascript width of a table cell one pixel too short?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, css

When you apply `border-collapse: collapse;` to a table to "meld" its cells' borders together, it starts causing problems in determining the widths of table cells in Javascript.  For example, look at this page:
http://game-point.net/misc/browserTests/scratchpads/jsTableWidth/
There are two tables, one with collapsed borders and one without.  If you click on a row in the one without collapsed borders, jQuery's innerWidth and outerWidth functions report what I would expect to see (the content width, and the content plus the border width respectively; there is no padding).

However, if you click on a row in the table with collapsed borders, you get browser-inconsistent behaviour, especially on the `clientWidth` property.  In Firefox, `clientWidth` is the same as `width()`.  In IE and Chrome, it's 1 pixel higher, and in Opera, it's the same as `width()`, but Opera's `width()` is too small.  In fact, the `width()` is one pixel too small in all the browsers I've tested except for Firefox.  So if you take a screenshot and the content is actually 80px, `width()` is 79px (jQuery gets it from the calculated CSS value).  Why is this?

I'm wanting to get the width of the actual content.  I can't seem to use `width()` because only Firefox gets that right with collapsed borders.  I can't use `outerWidth()` because that includes the borders (or maybe just one border, seeing as it's only 1px larger than the actual content width).  I can't use `clientWidth` because its value is inconsistent between browsers.  What should I do and why is `width()` 1px too short in most browsers when borders are collapsed?

Comment: use `.wrapInner()` method to wrap the content of cell with a div and get it's width.  http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: But that means you need to be inserting DOM elements all over the place to wrap the content... not exactly ideal?

Comment: tables can be a headache, why do you think they are not used for layout anymore? Wrapping content is solution for animating rows in them as well. Try animating a row without it...results are terrible

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean by "animating rows"?

Comment: as in....trying to use slideUp or slideDown animations to toggle visibility with animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem in every browser but Opera is actually something jQuery is doing with its `width()` function; it has custom hooks for width and height and it doesn't always return the true computed width.  When I use `window.getComputedStyle` to get the widths of these table cells, it does indeed give me the proper rendered width.  I am going to report Opera's `window.getComputedStyle` output as a bug, because it doesn't seem to give you the proper rendered width even when you bypass jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

In the collapsed border model, cells are not just "melded" they are *shared* by adjacent cells.

So say you have markup like this:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px">
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px">
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the collapsed border model, the width of this table is 102px.  There's 0.5px of border that's actually *outside* the table, then 0.5px of border, then 100px of cell, then 1px of border, then 100px of cell, then 0.5px of border, then 0.5px of border outside the table.  See the picture at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#collapsing-borders

So given that, what should a UA return for the various widths of the first cell?  Should it be 100px?  101px?  102px?  Something else?  Simply returning the content width plus the border widths would return 102px, but the actual space taken up by the cell is only 101px...

Furthermore, if jQuery is computing the content width itself it could run into this problem too, if it doesn't special-case border-collapsed cells somehow.

And there is no real spec for clientWidth, much less jQuery's width() and such, of course.  That sort of explains why the results you see are all over the place.

As for what you should do, if you actually know exactly what's going on with your borders, you should probably getBoundingClientRect().width (assuming browsers don't mess *that* up) and subtract off the half-widths of the borders.  If you need this to work with various different border widths, I'm not sure there's a great solution.

Comment: The width of the table you specify is 203px (I just tried it), with the extra 3px coming from 1px borders on the left and right of the table, and another 1px border between the two cells.  I don't really understand your explanation.

Comment: The rendered width is 203px.  The layout width is 202px.  The borders actually stick out of the table.  Please do see the picture at the link I provided...