# cell width attribute not copied correctly when border-collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm cloning a table header line by copying the tr html and then copying the th widths.  But this fails, because the widths are written as (width minus W) pixels when border: 'Wpx' and  border-collapse: 'collapse'. If border-collapse is not set, the widths are written correctly.

The code is simpleminded:

```
var arr = [];

// copy html, where abc is the destination <tr> and def is the source
$abc.html($def.html());

// now copy widths of table header cells 
$def.children().each(function()  {arr.push($(this).css("width"));});
$abc.children().each(function(index) {$(this).css("width", arr[index]);});
```

Fiddle shows the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/marvmartian/9z24j7vz/4/

A workaround (illustrated in the fiddle but commented out) is to check the final table sizes, and, if they are unequal, (hackily) add W to the widths before writing them.

This behavior seems like a bug (using Chrome).  Apparently it's a feature.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I can't see problem, actually, in firefox but i see it in chrome... (win7, latest versions of browsers)

Comment: Brain cramp, I don't see it in FF either.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, here is fix:

```
table.pvtTable tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    border: 6px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Chrome doesn't calculate cell widths as width + th border width (because border-collapse,on parent element, i guess?), if you add this in css - borders are included in final width. However, not sure which one (firefox or chrome) is right, this time. :)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9z24j7vz/5/

Comment: Turns out this isn't a general answer after all.  The only way to do this accurately is to put <div>s inside the cells and set the div sizes, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280798/why-is-the-javascript-width-of-a-table-cell-one-pixel-too-short.

Also getComputedStyle( ) seems to work in some cases as pointed out by one of the commenters to that thread.